# No 'inherited' item within FlashBuilder variables view

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm noticing now that in the variables view of flash builder, the 'inherited' variable is not appearing when I am stopped at a breakpoint. Is there a reason why 'inherited' may not appear sometimes? I have 'Group Inherited Members' selected in the menu for that view.